# Username validation through javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html

So here i am stuck. I want constraint for username that it should not start with any special characters. I think the regular expression is not working. Can anybody help to make it work?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>username test</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" onsubmit="user()" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p align="center"> <img src="gecp.png" width="144" height="144" alt="gecp" /></p>
  <p align="center">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="user" required/>
  </p><p id="p1"> </p>
  <p align="center">
    <label for="pass">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required/>
  </p><p id="p2"> </p>
  <p align="center">
    <input name="sub" type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
    <div align="center"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function user(){
    var name1=document.getElementById("user").value;
    var u1=/^[a-zA-Z]$/;
    if(name1.value.match(u1)){
        return true;
        }
    else { 
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML= "Invalid Input";
        name1.focus();
        return false;}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z]$/` means that it is one letter (total). You are probably missing the "anything afterwards" part, e.g. `.*`, `/^[a-zA-Z].*$/`. Also note that `RegExp.prototype.test` is probably more appropriate for this task than `match`.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is your friend

Comment: Alternatively, you can also remove the "end of string" and use `/^[a-zA-Z]/`. Your issue is that you are explicitly saying "start of string", "one letter", "end of string", in that order.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Can you help with this    Reg.prototype.test function in this code?

Comment: `match` just produces overhead in this case but will not produce different results. So while it is slightly more appropriate to use `test` here, it does not change whether the code works or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `match` function will return an array with the matching group of your string. What you need is the `test` function.

```
function user(){
var name1=document.getElementById("user").value;
var u1=/ˆ(\w+)(.+)$/;

if(u1.test(name1)){
    return true;
} else { 
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML= "Invalid Input";
    name1.focus();
    return false;
 }
}
```

You don't need to call the `value` property on `name1` since you already called it when you retrieved your value.
I also provided a optimized code :

```
function user(){
var name1=document.getElementById("user").value;
if(!/ˆ(\w+)(.+)$/.test(name1)) {
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML= "Invalid Input";
    name1.focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Regarding your Regex, from what i understand, you need to not have any special character at the beginning of the name. So I've use the `\w` to match only words, (`[a-Z]`). If you could also use a negative lookahead to make sure your string does not start with any special character. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/N2hhXj/1) is a regex101 to test your case.

the negative lookahead looks like this `(?![$%?&*])(.+)$`
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/tnIFV5/1) is an exampe with the negative lookahead

Comment: `match` will return `null` when there is no match and will therefore work identically, while perhaps producing slightly more overhead for creating the result.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yes, I think you are write. It is not showing any result.

Comment: @user22226 the second point he is making should however be correct, i wonder why you don't get any exceptions for your original code (my guess is you do but never bothered to check ;) )

Comment: @Nicolas I appreciate your efforts. but the funny thing is my browser is not showing anything. As i click on submit all texts just disappears. It is not responding on true or false condition.

Comment: There is probably an error in my code, check you console